# Domain from A, hosting from B, who'll receive the mail?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, email, transfer

I am tired of the Webhost I bought the domain and hosting from. Now, I now want to transfer my domain to Godaddy and shift to some other hosting.

My Question: Who'll receive the mails sent to the email address associated with the domain, ex: admin@mydomain.com

My webhost or Godaddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever you point your MX and DNS record to. You are the one that controls that.

Comment: So I can buy domain from Godaddy And once I've connected the domain with my webhost through editing nameservers, I can receive mails to my webhost?

Comment: @J.Ali Yes. You are in control. Your web host is not.

Comment: `MX` is a DNS record type.